# Validation for future date when entered date is in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, date

I need to validate a date for if it is a future valid date. While inputting date in the form I'm using the date format `dd/mm/yyyy` using Jquery validation plugin with dateITA rule. I've added the following validation method

```
 $.validator.methods.futuredocexp = function( value, element ) {    
    var now = new Date();
    var myDate = new Date(value);
    return this.optional(element) || myDate > now;    
 };
```

It only works if dates are in the american format like dd-mm-yyyy 
How can I make it work for dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: Try `value.split("/").join("-")`

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I've tried it but doesn't work i'm afraid

Comment: Where did you try this? And this fix is specific to date format with "/"

Comment: `dd-mm-yyyy` is not American date format. Also, do you mean that you are taking date input in format `dd/mm/yyyy` always and you have date in String format ?

Comment: Hi, i've tried in here: var myDate = new Date(value.split("/").join("-")); yes the string format is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @pippo: split and join is working, what exactly is the issue, can you please tell. See the answer.

Comment: Hi @OmSao thanks for your answer the problem is that even if the date is in the future jquery validation still says that is not valid.

Comment: @pippo: You don't need to use jquery validation, I updated my answer. Please refer, it will return true/false based on future date test.

Comment: Hi i've tried your method and console.log() return Input dateString was: 20/09/1984   Date Object is: Invalid Date
Is input dateStr a future date ??
jfalse

Comment: This is because you are giving input in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, which is not US(American format). Correct format for date input is `mm/dd/yyyy` format which I have shown in example. If you want to give input strictly for `dd/mm/yyyy` format then, you need to swap 1st and 2nd element of splitted array.

Comment: Please check the answer now.

Comment: I need to use it with jquery validation

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the dateString with `\` and then joining with `-` will do. Here is the example:

```js
var dateStringwithFwdSlash1 = "21/04/2050";  //  dd/mm/yyyy format
var dateStringwithFwdSlash2 = "21/04/2005";  //  dd/mm/yyyy format

Array.prototype.swapItems = function(a, b){
    this[a] = this.splice(b, 1, this[a])[0];
    return this;
}

function isItFutureDate(dateStr){
   var d = new Date(dateStr.split("/").swapItems(0,1).join("-"));
   var now = new Date();
   console.log("Input dateString was: "+dateStr+" \t Date Object is: " +d);
   console.log('Is input dateStr a future date ??');  // .getTime() returns milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970
   console.log((d.getTime()-now.getTime()) > 0 );
}


isItFutureDate(dateStringwithFwdSlash1);
isItFutureDate(dateStringwithFwdSlash2);
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to parse a string, reformat it, then give it to another parser to create a Date. Why not just parse the string and pass the values directly to the Date constructor? That way you avoid the built-in parser entirely and save an (unreliable) parse?

Comment: @RobG: You can't pass date string to `Date()`  in `dd-mm-yyyy` format, you have to convert it to format `mm-dd-yyyy` for Date constructor to consume. How, you would do that ? Please tell.

Comment: Having done `dateStr.split("/")` you now have the arguments you need to call the Date constructor directly. It comes done to a [two line function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639009/compare-and-filter-data-with-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format-from-current-date-using-u/28639241#28639241).

Comment: You are right. It didn't come to my mind :-(.